# How do I select diodes for battery charger repair?

Tags: diodes, battery-charging, amperage

I have an old vintage 1980's Sears battery charger that has two blown diodes. I wish to repair this charger and make it live again.

I would like to know how to determine what value of diode should be used.

I will say the obvious answer would be to just read the type number from the old ones and buy that model and install them. I WISH I could. I don't know why but when these things went they exploded the centers between the cathode and the anode was gone and there was a nice larg gap between the two. It's as if an EM pulse hit it.

Anyway, what I am having trouble with is, how do I select the correct diode?

I know that this charger is rated for 6-12 volt at 6 amperes. The diodes were fastened to two separate leads direct from the main transformer to the metal housing that the transformer is attached to.

I have tried to look up this information and have came up short on the whole answer.

I only find information about the voltage and not the amperage.

If I am recalling correctly some have said for the voltage selection you take the required through voltage and add 10V above the desired point and that's your value. Is this correct?

When it comes to the amperage I have found nothing. Any insight to this would be great.

Comment: The amperage can often be guessed by the physical size. Can you post a picture with a scale.

Comment: Many battery chargers have four diodes.  If your has two that are still OK, then use the same type.  Four diodes would be used in what is called a bridge, and all four would be identical.

Comment: Maybe post the model number of the charger.  You'd be surprised how often you can find schematics and plans for such things on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Some how I missed where you wrote that the charger was rated for six amperes.

That's the answer to your question.

You need diodes rated for at least 6 amperes.  Anything above 6 amperes is good.  If you have doubts, look at the "ampere" scale on the charger and use diodes rated for the maximum current the meter can display.

There are 10 ampere diodes available from various places that should do just fine.

I find 10A10 diodes cheap on non-specialist sites.  They are rated 1000 volts and 10 amperes.

You might also consider replacing all the diodes with a bridge (something like an NTE5322, 25A 200V)  that you can screw to a metal part of the charger housing.  The advantage is that the metal helps keep the diodes cool so they last longer.

---

Some of the switchable 6/12V chargers worked by switching from full bridge (12V) to half bridge (6V.)  That may make it more complicated to use a bridge rectifier in a single package like the NTE5322.

Comment: Thank you. When I was looking at the chargers inners I only found the two diodes. I will take a second look may be they are hiding behind or underneath something. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I googled for “vintage 1980's Sears battery charger circuit” and found a nice restoration post in [EDN](https://www.edn.com/resurrecting-a-6-amp-battery-charger/), with photos.

I did a crop&paste some of those photos to mark my comments:

1. General view of this Sears’ Charger.
2. Inside view - primary winding and Tap selection.
3. Selenium rectifiers, overcurrent protection and secondary side of transformer.
4. Voltage curve when charging 12V battery.
5. Open circuit voltage ~ 20Vpp.

I added comments to these pictures and at the end I will make some suggestions and brainstorming.

Please keep in mind I tried to maintain the overhauling very simple and low-tech, but just to add some operational and safety-related topics. I intentionally did not include here suggestions of a more sophisticated circuitry, as I see the spirit of the Charger to be simplistic.

[image: General view of this Sears’ Charger]

[image: Inside view - Primary winding and Tap selection]
[image: Selenium Rectifiers and Secondary side of Transformer]
[image: Voltage curve when charging 12V battery]
[image: Open circuit voltage ~ 20Vpp]

**About the diodes**: Based on these data, I suggest to use a full-wave bridge regulator as said by JRE earlier, mostly to provide *higher heat dissipation* when it is connected to the original plate of the rectifiers. But in your case, you just need to use half of the bridge, or 2 diodes.

**About current limiting or overcurrent protection**: I have read somewhere this existing protector (Photo #3, green arrow) may not age reliably; it can either trip at lower values (ok, but less effective) or not trip at all (dangerous). A suggestion would be to put in series to the output 1 or 2 High-beam headlamp(s) = 12V x 45~55W, to allow a short circuit current of 5A (for 1 lamp) or up to 10A (2 lamps) with a transformer showing voltages as in Photo #6. However, as the actual voltage differential between charger and battery will be smaller, even if the battery is huge and could have a negligible internal resistance, the transformer itself has an intrinsic winding resistance and actual initial charge current will be smaller than short-circuit. From similar past experiences, I would guess you would be able to charge with ~5A using 2 headlamps in parallel.

**Charging Current selection**: If you invest in an additional switching circuit, you could choose to charge with 50W//50W (2 headlamp) or just one 50W or maybe even a break-light lamp of 21W, providing about 5A, 2.5A or 1A, respectively. In this later case, *even for smaller motorcycle batteries* the charger would work.

**About overvoltage protection**: Short answer, there is **none**. However, by adding the headlamps the output impedance is increased and you gain **some time to react**. When combined with the battery internal resistance, the overvoltage spikes will be smaller than those ones in Photo #5. However, this charger should not be left unattended indefinitely. You should **check the battery voltage periodically** (battery AH size will dictate how often) to see if the final voltage of 13.8V to 14.5V is not exceeded depending of your charging strategy, otherwise the battery might be overcharging, overheating or at least excessively gassing (all undesirable).

**Desulphation feature**: When using the headlamps in series, the open circuit voltage (~20V peak) does not change, just the internal resistance of this simplistic Sears’ Charger. So, if a battery with partially sulphated plates is connected initially to the charger, its internal resistance will be higher, resulting in higher voltages - surely higher than 14V. Insisting to charge, this headlamp charger will behave as a rudimentary “constant”/limited current power supply. When battery starts to accept current and if recoverable, the voltage will gradually start to drop; based on several videos on Youtube, the voltage will start to increase later, as the battery really accepts the charge. So a partial recovery seems possible, but I don’t have personal experience with this and the topic seems quite polemic, with mixed results.